# rtc-config parameter getting stripped out of <amp-ad> tag

Tags: amp-html

We're looking to implement header-bidding with AMP ads, however our `rtc-config` parameter keeps getting stripped out.
Here's an example:

```
$adcode = '<div class="ad"><amp-ad width=300 height=250
            type="doubleclick"
            data-slot="'. esc_attr( $ad_slot ) .'"
            rtc-config=\'{
                "vendors": {
                "aps": {"PUB_ID": "xxxx","PARAMS":{"amp":"1"}} }}\'>
            json="' . esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $json_targeting ) ) . '">
        </amp-ad></div>';

return $adcode;
```

when output, returns this:

```
<amp-ad width="300" height="250" type="doubleclick" data-slot="xxxx/ab.m/story" json="{...}" class="i-amphtml-element i-amphtml-layout-fixed i-amphtml-layout-size-defined i-amphtml-layout" style="width: 300px; height: 250px;" data-amp-slot-index="0" data-a4a-upgrade-type="amp-ad-network-doubleclick-impl" data-google-query-id="xxxx">
... </amp-ad>
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong I'm see is that you are closing the `<amp-ad>` in the wrong place.

That misplaced close shouldn't cause the tag to last it's rtc-config parameter.

Check  this code on the sixth line.

```
$adcode = '<div class="ad"><amp-ad width=300 height=250
        type="doubleclick"
        data-slot="'. esc_attr( $ad_slot ) .'"
        rtc-config=\'{
            "vendors": {
            "aps": {"PUB_ID": "xxxx","PARAMS":{"amp":"1"}} }}\'
        json="' . esc_attr( wp_json_encode( $json_targeting ) ) . '">
    </amp-ad></div>';

return $adcode;
```